# TinyDB problem, cannot resolve symbol 'context'

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, tinydb

I want to use TinyDB in my Android app that built in Android Studio. To use the TinyDB, I need to add TinyDB class and write the context.

The context that need to be in the MainActivity:
`TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);`
And it shows "Cannot resolve symbol 'context'"

Context part in TinyDB class:

```
public TinyDB(Context appContext){
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefeences(appContext);
    context = appContext;
}
```

Should I replace 'context' with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Activity, the `Context` is Activity itself (=`this`):

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
```

Comment: The problem was that I put `TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);` before onCreate. I have tried using `this` and any other things.